# Undefined variables in EOD tag

Tags: php

PHP has never been my strongest point, but I am trying to learn. I'm having a little issue with my code below within the EOD tag. Lines 18 - 23 to be precise. I'm thinking it might be a small formatting error. But due to my inexperience with php I could be wrong.

```html
<?php

/* subject & account */

  $emailSub = 'Form Actioned';
  $emailAcc = 'test@test.co.uk';

/* data collection */

  $fnameField = $_POST ['fname'];
  $lnameField = $_POST ['lname'];
  $titleField = $_POST ['title'];
  $emailField = $_POST ['email'];

  $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
First Name: $fname <br>
Last Name: $lname <br> // <<-- This line is the one I'm suspicious of.
Company & Title: $title <br>
Email: $email <br>
EOD;

  $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
  $success = mail($emailAcc, $emailSub, $body, $headers);

/* result rendered as html */
  $result = <<<EOD

Success

EOD;
echo "$result";
```

Can anyone see a major issue with the EOD tag code? I have triple checked the names of the elements on my HTML and matched them precisely with the PHP but still no joy.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: _$fname_ and other variable should be like _$fnameField_ inside _$body_

Comment: I'm such a moron. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This :

```
/* subject & account */

  $emailSub = 'Form Actioned';
  $emailAcc = 'test@test.co.uk';

/* data collection */

  $fnameField = $_POST ['fname'];
  $lnameField = $_POST ['lname'];
  $titleField = $_POST ['title'];
  $emailField = $_POST ['email'];

  $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
First Name: $fnameField <br>
Last Name: $lnameField <br> // <<-- This line is the one I'm suspicious of.
Company & Title: $titleField <br>
Email: $emailField <br>
EOD;

  $headers = "From: $emailField \r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
  $success = mail($emailAcc, $emailSub, $body, $headers);

/* result rendered as html */
  $result = <<<EOD

Success

EOD;
echo "$result";
```